# PHP - Google_DriveService not found via composer

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api

I've already install google api php with composer, and upload vendor folder to my server.

```
php composer.phar require google/apiclient:^2.0
```

my code : getVideo.php

```
<?
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
define('ID_VIDEO', '0B9SXFdezvkZtOE9xVlVNR3U0a1U');
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("LOAD_VIDEO");
$client->setDeveloperKey("AIzaSyD1AVpO4qBgH0JmQOEU_xxxx");
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);
$client->setAccessType('offline_access'); 
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
 $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}
$service = new Google_DriveService($client);
$file = $service->files->get(ID_VIDEO);
$access_toke = json_decode($client->getAccessToken(), TRUE);
$access_toke = $access_toke['access_token'];
?>
<embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" src="<?= urldecode($file['embedLink']);?>&access_token=<?= $access_toke;?>" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" >
```

I got error code :

> Fatal error: Class 'Google_DriveService' not found in /home/myserver/public_html/getVideo.php on line 18

I can't find file with google_driveservice in folder vendor, am I missed anything?

Comment: Check on how you [install](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/php) your Google client library in the server. Also check if you properly added the client library by adding it as a dependency to your composer.json. Be reminded that there are some requirements need to run the Google APIs Client Library for PHP: PHP version 5.2.1 or greater, JSON PHP extension, Support for a writeable file system or Memcache, and cURL for the cURL IO method, or allow_url_fopen enabled for the Streams IO method. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [repository](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client-services/blob/master/src/Google/Service/Drive.php) the class name is `Google_Service_Drive`.

Update: Also according to the client's [readme](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client).

Comment: Thanks, I've already change with Google_Service_Drive but, show more error again, Fatal error: Call to undefined function GuzzleHttp\Handler\curl_reset()

Comment: Have you got the curl extension installed?

Comment: or maybe my php version is not support on 5.4?

Comment: The requirements on their docs specifically states `PHP 5.4.0 or higher`. If you're using any version of PHP 5.4, it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I have an error, for fix it I've changed Google_DriveService to Google_Service_Drive, working well.
change

```
$service = new Google_DriveService($client);
```

to

```
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
```